# How to transform disjunction of Future to Future of disjunction

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, scala-cats

I have the result of a method: 
`val res: Future[Int] Xor Future[String] = getResult(x)`

and would like to transform it and use it as `Future[Int Xor String]`

I could not extrapolate my use case from the [herding cats blog](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/stacking-future-and-either.html) and am not sure whether a monad transformer would be the right tool here, perhaps rather some form of `traverse`?

`Xor` from cats stands in for any disjunction. Scalaz `\/` or stdlib `Either` would be fine as well (though I would prefer a biased disjunction).

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as `sequence` allows you to turn a `F[G[A]]` into a `G[F[A]]` when `F` has a `Traverse` instance and `G` is applicative, `bisequence` lets you turn a `F[G[A], G[B]]` into a `G[F[A, B]]` if `F` has a `Bitraverse` instance (and `G` is applicative).

Cats has provided a `Bitraverse` implementation for [at least a couple of versions](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/800) (I'm using 0.6.0-M2 here), so you can just write this:

```
import cats.data.Xor, cats.std.future._, cats.syntax.bitraverse._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def flip[A, B](x: Xor[Future[A], Future[B]]): Future[Xor[A, B]] = x.bisequence
```

`Bitraverse` is a little like Scalaz's `Zip` or `Cozip` (mentioned in the other answer), but it's more generic in that instances can be defined for any type constructor with two type arguments (assuming it has the appropriate semantics), not just tuples or disjunction.

Comment: thanks Travis, works fine for me. I wish I would understand better what I am doing here :)

Comment: @kostja There are (almost) always people around to answer questions more interactively in the [Gitter room](https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats)!

Comment: In this case the key is generalizing from `Traverse` and `sequence`, which are a little simpler and more widely applicable, so building up intuitions about how to use those is likely to help.

Comment: could you please update the answer to cats 0.8.1? I assumed that importing `cats.instances.either._`, `cats.implicits._` & `cats.syntax.bitraverse._` would be enough, but even after importing `*.all._` `x.bisequence` refuses to compile with `value bisequence is not a member of Either[scala.concurrent.Future[Int],scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]]`. Scala 2.11.8

Comment: @kostja Sure, but it's probably worth a new question (linking to this one), since there are a lot of differences between `Either` and `Xor` (and since a lot has changed in recent Cats versions).

Answer (score 3):

Scalaz has `Functor.counzip`, but there is no `counzip` in `scalaz.syntax.functor` so we need to call it on `Functor[Future]` directly :

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._
import scalaz.{\/, Functor}

val disj: Future[Int] \/ Future[String] = \/.right(Future.successful("foo"))
Functor[Future].counzip(disj)
// Future[Int \/ String] : Success(\/-(foo))
```

Scalaz also has a `Cozip` type class which gives you the inverse : `F[A \/ B] => F[A] \/ F[B]`.