# How to transform Either[Future[A], Future[B]] to Future[Either[A, B]]

Tags: scala, applicative, either, scala-cats

I have an instance of `Either[Future[A], Future[B]]` and I would like to transform it to `Future[Either[A, B]]`.

Since [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327257), [cats 0.8.1](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/tree/v0.8.1) has been released, changing the structure of the library and dropping `Xor` in favor of `Either`, which is right-biased in 2.12.

Thus the method described in the previous accepted answer does not work anymore. I have tried to find the appropriate imports but failed.

```
cats.instances.either._
cats.implicits._ 
cats.syntax.bitraverse._
```

looked plausible but unfortunately does not work. Compilation still fails with `value bisequence is not a member of Either[scala.concurrent.Future[A],scala.concurrent.Future[‌​B]]`

Widening the imports to `*.all._` did not change the compiler error.

I am on scala 2.11.8 as not all libraries the project depends upon have released a version for 2.12

Comment: `either.fold(_.map(Left(_)), _.map(Right(_)))`, but how is this related to cats?

Comment: I've tried this with cats 0.8.1 and scala 2.11.8 and 2.12.1, and `bisequence` on `Either[Future[A], Future[B]]` works in both versions. Do you have an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope? It's required for `Applicative[Future]`

Comment: @Kolmar - yes, I do import an implicit `ExecutionContext`. This is strange, have cleaned the project before compilation. Do you use the same 3 imports I did?

Comment: Deleted my answer. Sure looks like you're missing an import now that I figured out that there is syntax and instances for either of a `Bitraverse`. Try adding `import cats.syntax.either._` to see if that doesn't move it forward.

Comment: Oh, I've reproduced your issue. Try with only a single import `cats.implicits._`. Seems your imports are interfering with each other.

Comment: @wheaties, Kolmar - thank you guys, conflicting imports have been the issue. My instinct was to widen the imports, not to narrow them down and this instinct was wrong. Your plain scala solution works great as well and I will be using it from now on. Travis Brown has provided a nice solution using cats to my previous question, so I tried to continue using it.

Comment: For posterity: [The Cats import guide](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html)

Comment: @PeterNeyens - ah, the last paragraph is golden :) thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have compiled the answers from the comments for reader convenience:

1: you can do it in plain scala (using `cats.Functor` for the definition here), courtesy of @wheaties & @jean-philippe-pellet

```
def eitherFmap[F[_], A, B](either: Either[F[A], F[B])(implicit F: Functor[F]): F[Either[A, B]] =   
either.fold(f => F.map(f)(Left(_)), f => F.map(f)(Right(_)))
```

2: cats `bisequence` refused to compile because of conflicting imports: a single import is enough here - courtesy of @kolmar

```
import cats.instances._
...
val futureOfEither = eitherOfFutures.bisequence
```

3: read the [cats import guide](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html) to avoid the issue in the future - courtesy @peter-neyens